# How can I compile programs in Java 6 rather than Java 7 or 8?

Tags: java, eclipse

how can I make Java programs in Java 6 rather than Java 7 or 8, so that most machines can run my programs. Do I download a separate JDK? Do I change the compiler's compliance level? Or do I download a separate JRE. I am very confused, and I really need help.

Thank you so much!

Oh and I am using the IDE Eclipse.

Comment: Let me tell you, you should accept an answer here when your problem is solved or you find it useful for you. It will help others looking at your question to know the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: How to accept an answer? You should click on the Right Tick of the answer which you want to accept, it will be visible to you below the up down arrows of each answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If compiling from the command line, it can be done by using the following.

`javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 (files)`

Eclipse uses its own java compiler. In the Eclipse IDE, go to `Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler`, and change the `Compiler compliance level`. `1.8` is for Java 8, select `1.6` if you need Java 6. Preferences are global for all java projects of your workspace.

If you want a specific configuration you can untick `Use default compliance settings` (if not already unticked), and change `Generated .class files compatibility` and `Source compatibility` separately.

[image: Eclipse Preferences > Java > Compiler]

If you'd like to make the change just for the current project, go to `Project > Properties > Java Compiler`, tick `Enable project specific settings` (if not already ticked), then as before, set the compiler configuration to what you need.

Comment: Even though OP specifically asks for Eclipse, this is useful for those who find this article in the future.

Comment: I still think that this should remain as an answer... It really does suck when people try to find solutions via Google and old answers are deleted.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank you so much I really appreciate it. Both of your answers were great and it really cleared up a lot.

Comment: It is not a recommanded practice to have `Generated .class files compatibility` and `Source compatibility` not in sync. I recommend to change the `compiler compiance level` directly, it will change both.

Comment: @Jmini - thanks for the edit. I was a little worried about Eclipse complaining about needing a JRE at v1.6 when I changed the whole lot.

Answer (score 4):

You should download JDK 6 on your system and point Eclipse to use it.

However if you are using command line, then there is no difference in How you compile it,

**To Compile**

`javac FileName.java`

**To Run**

`java ClassName`

**FYI**

[JDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) is the Java Development Kit, which has all the tools to do Java development.

**JRE** is Java RunTime Environment, which has Java's libraries and [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) which can run the Java programs.

*In simple words you can say, to develop Java code you need JDK but if you ONLY want to run it, then you will be done only with JRE.*

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse IDE has its own java compiler. You can set the "compiler compiance level" from the preferences: (Menu > Windows > Preferences)

[image: Eclipse preferences > compiler]

"1.8" is Java 8...

Preferences are global for all java projects of your workspace.

It is also possible to define it for each java project (context menu > properties) on the project.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, Go to Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler and you can select 1.6 as the compliance level.